# Reminding application

Tags: android, alarm

I still a new to Android Developments and I want to make an application that has an entity for setting a reminder depends on some calculation that I set it on EditText (to let user see what left to reminder to start) with dialog shown after pressing a button.

The reminder not depend on date and the postpone will be on fixed time period.

All values I set it to SharedPreferences before and after calculation.

I tried to search for it and all I found is about taking date from calender and tried a some solution in this form but it was not clear to me to understand it :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java Util Timer class to do what you want.

you can see [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Development-Class/UsejavautilTimertoscheduleatasktoexecuteonce5secondshavepassed.htm) an example.

Comment: Thanks ... going to try it